# laravel blade - show only one data from database

Tags: laravel

I have a table with multiple fields called "skills" . how do I show only one(first) data associated with "skills" .

```
  @foreach ($others as $other )
        @if ($other->type == 'skills')
        <div class="col-md-6 p-0">
            <img src="{{$other->photoOrVideo}}" class="imgbg-col" alt="imghome">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 centered">
            <div class="detailcontent">
                <div class="subheading">{{$other->type}}</div>
                <div class="heading">{{$other->titleOrName}}</div>
                <div class="textdetail">{{$other->description}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif
        @endforeach
```

in my controller-

```
 public function index()
{
    $sliders = Slider::latest()->with('service')->get();
    $clients = OurClient::all();
    $galleries = Gallery::all();
    $services = Service::all();
    $others = Others::all();
    return view('frontend.pages.home',compact('services','galleries','clients','others','sliders'));

}
```

this is showing the same data twice. I want only the first data

Comment: What is query for `$others`? Query itself should be modified to fetch only 1 record

Comment: there are more sections to get data from "$others" . but in this section i only want one data

Comment: If you get multiple outputs containing 'skill` then you have problems in join or something like that. You could solve it in blade view, but correct way would be solving your query

Comment: i get all the datas containing "skills". But I just One Data containing skill

Comment: Please update the question with the code that extracts data with skills in your controller. Otherwise we can't help you a lot wit Q-A ping-pong.

Comment: ok i updated the codes

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. changed the blade file

```
<div class="row">
  <?php $count = 0; ?>
  @foreach ($others as $other )
    @if ($other->type == 'skills')
      <?php if($count == 1) break; ?>

      <div class="col-md-6 p-0">
        <img src="{{$other->photoOrVideo}}" class="imgbg-col" alt="imghome">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 centered">
        <div class="detailcontent">
          <div class="subheading">{{$other->type}}</div>
          <div class="heading">{{$other->titleOrName}}</div>
          <div class="textdetail">{{$other->description}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php $count++; ?>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</div>
```